# How to save all deep learning model parameters in Python?

Tags: python, keras, parameters, model

Is it possible to save all parameters from the LSTM model implemented in keras?
When I apply the following functions:

```
model = load_model("model_RNN.h5")
for layer in model.layers:
    g = layer.get_config()
    weights = layer.get_weights()
```

only get parameters related to the last layer (17 weights)?
My LSTM network architecture is as follows, containing 7505 parameters. How can I save all 7505 parameters?

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 10, 32)            4352
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 16)                3136
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 17
=================================================================
Total params: 7,505
Trainable params: 7,505
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call "parameters" are called "weights" in Keras, and of course a `Model` instance has a `get_weights()` method that you can use to get a list containing all the weights of all layers:

```
weights = model.get_weights()
```

Then you can save this list using whatever technique you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use model.summary() for checking the layers of network and you can follow the below link to save and load the keras models.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/

Comment: As you can see, I used model.summary() to show the model architecture. I saw before the page you added, in which example, the values ​​of all parameters cannot be read.